# Squeeze superscripts and subscripts around bracketed expressions in display math

Tags: brackets, superscripts, subscripts

Consider a bracketed term in display math, like this.

[image: LaTeX output]

Is there any way to squeeze the space between the super/sub-scripts and the bracketed term? e.g.

[image: Desired output]

where I've modified the image to create the desired effect. Apologies if this is a duplicate. I trawled through results from a few different searches and didn't find the same question asked anywhere.

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{\frac{dx}{dy}}{\frac{dz}{dt}}\right)^{0.01}_i
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may adjust the indices half manually e.g. like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\subsup}[3]{{#1}_{\mkern-4mu #2}^{\mkern-4mu #3}}

\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{\frac{dx}{dy}}{\frac{dz}{dt}}\right)_i^{0.01} \quad
\subsup{\left(\frac{\frac{dx}{dy}}{\frac{dz}{dt}}\right)} {i}{0.01}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a pretty good fix, even though its manual. Is there any way of making this whole process automatic? i.e. so that LaTeX decides how much space to squeeze?

Comment: @Warrick TeX looks at the box, so AFAIK it can't decide if there is space to narrow the indices. E.g. for [...] the indices made by `\subsup` are too narrow, but with (...) and {...} they look fine.